# Finding words within paragraph using Python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Let say I have the following words, `Test_wrds = ['she', 'her','women']` that I would like to see whether any one of them present in the following `str` paragraph,

```
text= "What recent discussions she has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on women."
```

The question is,  How to find these `Test_wrds` in `text` and bold them in different colours as well as count them how many times `Test_wrds` appeared in `Para`. So I am expecting output something like this,

```
text= " What recent discussions **she** has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on **women**.
```

So far, I have written the following codes:

```
text=" Q: What recent discussions she has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on women."
Test_wrds = ['she', 'her','women']

import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
doc = nlp(text)
# word split
Wrd_token=[token.orth_ for token in doc]
```

I am not getting an idea on how to proceed further after this.  I used `spacy` as I found to be powerful and easy for my future coding.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in order to count how many times each word from **Test_wrds** list exists in **text** you can use ORTH which is an ID of the verbatim text content (see [here](https://spacy.io/api/lexeme#attributes)).

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.attrs import ORTH

text=" Q: What recent discussions she has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on women."
Test_wrds = ['she', 'her','women']

nlp = English()

doc = nlp(text)

# Dictionairy with keys each word's id representation and values the number of times this word appears in your text string
count_number = doc.count_by(ORTH)

for wid, number in sorted(count_number.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    # nlp.vocap.strings[wid] gives the word corresponding to id
    if nlp.vocab.strings[wid] in Test_wrds:
        print(number, nlp.vocab.strings[wid])
```

Output:

```
1 she
1 women
```

Second, in order to replace each word with bold you can try

```
import re

# Avoid words followed by '.' without empty space
text = text.replace('.', ' .')

lista = text.split()

for word in Test_wrds:
    if word in lista:
        indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(lista) if j==word] # Find list indices
        for index in indices:
            lista[index] = re.sub(lista[index], '**'+word+'**', lista[index])
            
new_text = ' '.join(lista)
```

Output :

```
>>> new_text
'Q: What recent discussions **she** has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on **women** .'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 1. Don't we need to split the sentences into words (I cant see in ur coding) 2. Is it possible to avoid for loop and use list compression or similar kind of techniques as for loop slow.

Comment: Also, your code seems wrong, the output is not bolded *She* word. Only bolded "women"

Comment: The text is automatically split into tokens by applying spacy's models (i.e., the line with `nlp(text)`. Iterating over the resulting object is per default a token iterator, so the answer *is* correct.

Comment: For the second part of word replacement I have just edited my answer. I'm using re library. I'm splitting the text string and replacing the desired words inside the list. Finally by using .join I'm creating the final output. As for the space before '.' you can just do another replacement of ' .' with '.'